# arabic word when export to excel asp.net

Tags: c#, excel

I got a problem when export an arabic work to excel from c# code behind:
the code I use for :

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=Employee.xls";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Write("السبت");// this word mean Saturday in arabic
        Response.End();
        Application.UnLock();
```

but after I open the excel file its look like :
[image]

why the word look like this and how to fix it ? 
and if you see in the second row the size of the word didn't fit with the size of the cell how to do it ? 
another question : how to color the background of the cell from c# code behind and how to combine cell ?
thx any way

Comment: cange your char set here `HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";` to read the following and see what happens 
add this line toHTTPContext.CUrrent.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
`HTTPContext.CUrrent.Response.Charset = "windows-1254";`

Comment: the word appear like question mark : ??????

Comment: Please ask one question at a time: Encoding, cell size, background color.

Comment: ok I need the answer just for the encoding

Comment: You have not actually created an Excel file. You just created a text file, served it with an xls extension and Excel MIME type. A real .xls file is a binary file. Instead, what you should do is use a library to create a proper Excel file. Look into libraries like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) and [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML).

Answer (score 0):

I took your example rewrote it on my end just now tested it and everything works fine
I wonder if you are experiencing a `Culture` issue

keep in mind the filename I am assigning on my end and passing it to a Method

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable table, string fileName)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
    context.Response.Charset = "windows-1254"; //ISO-8859-13 ISO-8859-9  windows-1254
    //Begin Table
    context.Response.Write("<table><tr>");

    //Write Header
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        context.Response.Write("<th>" + column.ColumnName + "</th>");
    }
    context.Response.Write("</tr>");

    //Write Data
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        context.Response.Write("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            context.Response.Write("<td>" + row[i].ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + "</td>");
        }
        context.Response.Write("</tr>");
    }

    //End Table
    context.Response.Write("</table>");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: where is the data coming from that you are populating the Excel here is my exact method where I populate excel from WebPage passing in a DataTable

Comment: works like a Charm you need to check your system Environment setting as well Region ect...

Comment: look into this as well if things keep mucking up on your end `Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());`

Comment: still a question mark : but I used EPPlus.dll library and it's works for me right now ... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

use 1256 rather than 1254 it's working good :)

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
context.Response.Charset = "windows-1256"; //ISO-8859-13 ISO-8859-9  windows-1256
```